# !Undefined control sequence.\Description

Tags: errors, acmart

I am using texmaker and I git this error:

```
!Undefined control sequence.\Description
```

The error is form the description in images I think.

```
  \begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sample-franklin}
  \caption{1907 Franklin Model D roadster. Photograph by Harris \&
    Ewing, Inc. [Public domain], via Wikimedia
    Commons. (\url{https://goo.gl/VLCRBB}).}
  \Description{A woman and a girl in white dresses sit in an open car.}
\end{figure}
```

any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As the error message says, your error is in the `\Description{A woman...}` command. I think that you want `\caption{A woman...}`.

Comment: Thanks butI think this is not the problem because I already have the caption. I am using the template of a conference.

Comment: If you're using an unusual "template" (I assume this is something in a `\documentclass` command), we need to know which it is.  Otherwise, it's impossible to tell why you're getting that error.  But facially, the error says that `\Description` isn't a valid command; are you sure you've spelled it correctly, capitalized it correctly, etc?

Comment: Sure! the template is sample-sigconf for ACM conferences. I download from here : https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template @dgoodmaniii

Comment: I actually did not change the spelling in the template file so it should be correct.

Comment: I am using \documentclass[sigconf]{acmart} @dgoodmaniii

Comment: Try using \description (small D) and moving the \caption to after the \description.

Comment: @Fintan No, `acmart.cls` defines a macro called `\Description`, used in the way the OP uses it. `\description` would be something else.

Comment: Can you show us the complete error from the `.log` file?

Comment: please always provide a complete small document so people can run it and see the error, it is not possible to debug that fragment.

Comment: As far as I can see, `\Description` does nothing except setting a conditional to true and the final effect is that if *some* figure has a `\Description`, then all should (or you'd get a warning). The text is not used at any stage.

Comment: do you mean that I comment out the \Description in the figure{}? @egreg

Comment: @TorbjørnT. the log fig is added.

Comment: This before  of `\Description{}` solves the problem: `\def\Description#1{Now a can say that #1}`. This also: `\newcommand\Definition[1]{\em #1}`.  This only maybe: <your lost and unknown definition>.   A control sequence is `\whatever` that you (or LaTeX) have defined previously. Do you understand now the problem?

Comment: @user216506 No. I mean that without a real minimal example the code cannot be debugged.